# Inconsistent results when using arrayformula within Googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula that will calculate the working hours between two dates.

It works perfectly well when referring a few lines and ranges. As the data in this sheet is going to be automatically added to over time I wanted to use arrayformula to automatically calculate the duration for these new rows.

However when used within arrayforumla the values are unpredictably different.
I can't make any sense of why it's different.

Below is an example;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWZwpnkp2MPyM-EppjOYHRcMEcblscU70R62uf691Xw/edit#gid=0

Any suggestions as to why the formula is behaving differently would be greatly appreciated!

Edit

For posterity;

[image]

Formula that worked when inline (COL C);

```
=TEXT((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,1,F$7:F$9)-1)*($G$2-$F$2)+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,B2,1,F$7:F$9),MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),$F$2,$G$2),$G$2)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,A2,1,F$7:F$9)*MOD(A2,1),$F$2,$G$2),"[hh]:mm:ss")
```

Forumla that didn't work in arrayformula (COL D);

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(ROW(B:B)=1, "Array Formula Duration", 
        IF(ISBLANK(B:B),"",
(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2:A,B2:B,1,F$7:F$9)-1)*($G$2-$F$2)+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2:B,B2:B,1,F$7:F$9),MEDIAN(MOD(B2:B,1),$F$2,$G$2),$G$2)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2:A,A2:A,1,F$7:F$9)*MOD(A2:A,1),$F$2,$G$2)
  )
```

)
)

Forumla that sorted it (COL E);

```
={"Array Formula Duration";map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(b="",,TEXT((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(a,b,1,F7:F9)-1)*(G2-F2)+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(b,b,1,F7:F9),MEDIAN(MOD(b,1),F2,G2),G2)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(a,a,1,F7:F9)*MOD(a,1),F2,G2),"[hh]:mm:ss"))))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
={"Array Formula Duration";map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(b="",,TEXT((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(a,b,1,F7:F9)-1)*(G2-F2)+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(b,b,1,F7:F9),MEDIAN(MOD(b,1),F2,G2),G2)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(a,a,1,F7:F9)*MOD(a,1),F2,G2),"[hh]:mm:ss"))))}
```

Comment: I've no idea what that does, but it's working!

I'd love to learn why it wasn't working to begin with if you know why?

Either way, thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: `map\lambda` is a technique is to apply a single row function into array style without much fuss. If you look at it very closely I've haven't literally changed much from your original working formula other than applying the map\lambda to it.